# PostgreSQL Permission Problem: Read-Only Role Denied Access to Table. SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I'm encountering a permission problem in PostgreSQL where I've set up a read-only role and granted it SELECT permissions on all tables, sequences, and schema. However, I'm still getting a "permission denied" error when attempting to query one of the tables.

Roles and Permissions:

1. I've created a read-only role called *exampledbro*.
2. I've granted CONNECT, USAGE on schema public, and SELECT on all tables in schema public to the *exampledbro* role.
3. I've also granted USAGE on all sequences in schema public to the *exampledbro* role.
4. Additionally, I've used ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES to grant SELECT on tables to exampledbro.

Below are the list of statements that I have run as **master** user for reference,

```
    CREATE ROLE exampledbro;
    REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE exampledb FROM exampledbro;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE exampledb TO exampledbro;
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO exampledbro;
    GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO exampledbro;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO exampledbro;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO exampledbro;
    ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO exampledbro;
    CREATE USER exampledbbi WITH password 'password';
    GRANT exampledbro TO exampledbbi;
```

Expectation:

After granting the necessary permissions to the *exampledbro* role, I expect the following behavior:

Read-Only Access: The *exampledbro* role should have read-only access to all tables, sequences, and schemas in the PostgreSQL database.

No Permission Denied Errors: When querying tables, selecting data, or accessing sequences in the public schema, I do not expect to encounter any "permission denied" errors.

Successful Queries: Queries executed by the *exampledbbi* user, which has been assigned the *exampledbro* role, should successfully retrieve data from the tables in the public schema without any access issues.

Actual:

I am able to connect using newly created user *exampledbbi* and able to view the list of tables. But, while trying to run a select statement, it fails with permission denied error

`SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for table orders`

PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 14.6

What other privileges should be given to run the select on any tables in `public` schema in **exampledb**? Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried running `SELECT schemaname, tablename, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE grantee = 'exampledbro';` to ensure that there are no missing or incorrect default privileges